# NullPointerException with Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, nullpointerexception, requestdispatcher

I am calling a `Servlet` using its URL address. This is the URL I am typing

```
http://localhost:7001/ryan/olympics?action=selectCatalog&id=1
```

This is the Servlet's URL for sure; if I change the address I get

```
page not found
```

This is the code for the Servlet.

```
public class Servlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
        implements javax.servlet.Servlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Servlet() {
    super();
}

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    System.out.println("*** initializing controller servlet.");
    super.init(config);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


String action = request.getParameter("action");



if (action.equals("selectCatalog")) {
      String categoryId = request.getParameter("id");

      ProductModelDAO dao4 = new ProductModelDAOImpl("jpac");
      if (categoryId != null && !categoryId.trim().equals("")) {
          CategoryDAO dao1 = new CategoryDAOImpl("jpac");

    try {
        Category category = dao1.getCategoryName(categoryId);
        request.setAttribute("category", category);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Product> products = dao4
            .getProductsByCategory(categoryId);
        request.setAttribute("products", products);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    url = "SelectCatalog.jsp";

 RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher =
  getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

I get the `NullPointerException` pointing to the `RequestDispatcher`'s line. Any help?

Comment: Try change `"SelectCatalog.jsp"` to `"/SelectCatalog.jsp"`

Comment: Where under the `webapp` (or equivalent) folder is `SelectCatalog.jsp`?

Comment: CAMOBAP Thanks a lot. That was causing the error. Post your reply as an answer so I can mark it if you would like to. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `"SelectCatalog.jsp"` to `"/SelectCatalog.jsp"`, because, as I understand, You want to use an `absolute path`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a relative path you have to use:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(url);
```

in place of:

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

request.getParameter("action");

code is written in doPost method. Are you invoking this servlet from doPost method of calling servlet? URL parameters will not be used by doPost method.